# Replace views in detail part of the screen after user's action

Tags: ios, swift, view

I am new to Swift and app development. I have a design question. I am trying to make a view that contains a slider, but that as soon as the "touch up inside" action is performed, is replaced by a progress bar + button. If the button is pressed, then we go back to showing only the slider. This view will be not take the whole screen, only part of it.

What would be the best way of doing this? I have already investigated several options:

**1. using a navigation controller with a segue triggered by the slider that goes into a new scene with a progress bar & button**.

**2. creating a custom view with two properties: a slider and a custom view (progress bar & button). The slider can be laid out using interface builder, and the custom view can be loaded from a nib file when needed.**

**3. creating a custom view with two properties: a slider and a custom view (progress bar & button). The new progress bar and button are created programmatically whenever the action is triggered on the slider.**

I have already tried options 1 and 2 to some extent with no success. Since I am a beginner, I am trying to use the IB as much as possible. What is the best option (if any) from the list?

Comment: So you want to make a progress bar and a button popup when the user finishes adjusting the slider, is this correct? I just want to get on the same page before posting an answer.

Comment: I would lay it all out in Interface Builder and just use the `hidden` properties of the various elements to control which are visible at any point

Comment: Thanks for your comments! @The Beanstalk: yes, that's correct. The progress bar and button should pop up where the slider was.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly on the Storyboard without needing to create a custom view class, but you'll need a few lines of code in any case. Just drag a Slider into your View, and then drag a button and a progress view directly on top of that. Now select the button, and in the Attributes inspector, tick the box next to "Hidden". Do the same with the progress bar. Then just open the assistant editor and connect references to all 3 of those. You'll also need to create an action for the button (I've called it `change`), and make sure you leave the `type` field as `AnyObject`. Add the following line inside `ViewDidLoad`:

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: Selector("change:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

This line just makes it so that `change` gets called anytime the user uses the slider. Obviously change `slider` to whatever you name your `UISlider`. You can implement the `change` function like this:

```
@IBAction func change(sender: AnyObject) {
    slider.hidden = !slider.hidden
    button.hidden = !button.hidden
    progressBar.hidden = !progressBar.hidden
}
```

This is a simple implementation that just toggles between true and false for each of the items, but you'll probably want to do it differently depending on what this project does.

Now, if you want to put this functionality in multiple places in your app it might be easiest to create a custom view using the same concept as above, in which case check out [this tutorial](http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6) on how to create an IBDesignable UIView.